# SonarQube Integration with XQuery

Tags: sonarqube, xquery, marklogic

I want to integrate SonarQube with XQuery. I got the plugin from GitHub.
https://github.com/malteseduck/sonar-xquery-plugin

In the readme page, below link is given for setup and upgrade of sonar. 
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade

But the link is not working. Can anyone please help me with the any other link I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade . sidenote google is your friend, i was just searching for "Sonar Setup and Upgrade"